# Determine $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ derivable such that : $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f'(x)+f(x)=f(0)+f(1). $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

I want to determine the functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ derivable such that
$$
 \forall x\in\mathbb{R}, f'(x)+f(x)=f(0)+f(1).\tag{$*$}
$$
For that, if $f$ a differentiable function, check $(*)$. We set $C=f(0)+f(1)$, so $f$ is a solution of $y'+y=C$. The solutions of this equation are the functions $x\mapsto C+De^{−x}$ with $D\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, there exists $D\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)= C+De^{−x}$. Then
$$
C=f(0)+f(1)=2C+D(1+e^{-1})\Longleftrightarrow D=-\frac{C}{1+e^{-1}}.
$$
Hence $f(x)= C\left(1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-1}}\right)e^{−x}$.

But, I see in an indication that the solutions are of the form
$$
f(x)=−\lambda(1+e^{−1})+\lambda e^{-x}\text{ with }\lambda\in\mathbb{R}
$$
please where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, whatever you have done is right, except what happens if $f(0) = -f(1)$? In that case, $C = 0$, and the zero function satisfies the equation above.

I had something slightly different. If you have $f(x) = f(0) + f(1) + De^{-x}$, plugging in $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ yields $D = -f(1) = -f(0)e$ and thus $f(1) = f(0)e$ is the only condition required. Consequently, we have
$$f(x) = f(0)(1 + e) - f(0)e^{1-x} = f(0)(1 + e - e^{1-x})$$ as the general form of $f(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, under the constraint that $f(1) = f(0)e$ (which is automatically true if you check it upon substituting $x = 1$). You can check that this indeed satisfies the differential equation. In particular, when $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, this also holds.

**Conclusion**: All functions of the form
$$ f(x) = A(1 + e - e^{1-x}) $$
for any constant $A \in \mathbb{R}$.